# Python Urllib2 Post-ing Utf-8 data gives 400 error

Tags: python, xml, soap, urllib2

so my problem lies in trying to POST some data for a SOAP request using urrlib2.

The data is the only thing that contains any non-ascii characters.

```
API_ENDPOINT = "https://www.foo.com/WebService/v1_2/fooService.asmx"
headers = {
        'Host': 'www.foo.com',
        'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
        'Content-length': "%d" % len(data_xml),
        'SOAPAction': '"https://www.foo.com/SaveJob"',
}
data = some xml unicode stuff
request = urllib2.Request(url=API_ENDPOINT, data=data_xml.encode("utf-8"), headers=headers)
```

Gives me this error:

```
content = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
  return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 400, in open
  response = meth(req, response)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 513, in http_response
  'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 438, in error
  return self._call_chain(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 372, in _call_chain
  result = func(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 521, in http_error_default
  raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

Comment: I could, but the code is already written using basic urrlib2, so I don't want to redo it all in a SOAP library. It all works perfectly except for the case of POSTing unicode data like this.

Answer (score 2):

And I fixed it. For anyone who searches on google later, the issue was in explicitly setting the Content-Length header before I encoded the data as utf-8. Removing the content-length header (which is set automatically by urllib2) fixed the issue.

If you wish to explicitly set the content length, it needs to be done after encoding the data as utf-8.

Comment: If you want to set the `Content-Length` you can—just do `data8 = data.encode('utf-8')`, set it to `len(data8)` instead of `len(data)`, and send `data=data8` in the `Request`. But yes, as you say, you don't even need to set this. You also don't need to set `Host`.

Comment: True. I have edited my answer to include some of your comment.

Comment: In Python, it is so easy to write `Request('http://' + ipAddress + '/api/postmethod')` when `type(ipAddress)` is `unicode` :-)